# Is it decidable whether a Turing Machine will visit every non-end state from input x?

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

L = {w#x | w,x ∈{0,1}∗ and Turing Machine Mw with input x visits every non-end state at least once}

I believe this problem is undecidable.

My proof would consist of me reducing L to a Halting Problem; however, the structure of these proofs seem incosistent and inconclusive. I would appreciate if I could have some constructive feedback.

My understanding of the proof:

1. Create R which decides L
2. Construct algorithm S, which decides Atm (which we reduce to L)
3. Contradiction because Atm is undecidable

This is the skeleton to most Turing Machine dicidibility related  proofs I have read on the internet.

Comment: I suggest reviewing other similar proofs that were given in class.

Comment: unfortunately as i said the structure of these proofs seem incosistent and inconclusive

Comment: You need to reduce the halting problem _to_ $L$: you're saying that, if I could decide $L$, I could decide the halting problem for Turing machines. You seem to know what you need to do, so go ahead and do it: figure out a way of deciding the halting problem using a supposed ability to decide $L$.

Comment: "reducing L to a Halting Problem" does not allow you to state anything about the decidability of $L$. You need to reduce in the opposite direction.

Comment: @chi, reduction to Halting problem leads to undecibility of initial problem, which is needed to be shown.

Comment: @rus9384 No. The set of even naturals reduces _to_ the halting problem, yet it is decidable. One needs to reduce _from_ the halting problem to prove undecidability, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It's undecidable because you could use it to decide halting.

Because the number of states in a Turing machine is finite you can enumerate all $2^n$ combinations of possible non-end states. Run the algorithm against all of them.

If the algorithm returns yes for a group of states that includes an original end state then the machine halts.

Halting problem is undecidable so the algorithm cannot be executed by a Turing machine.